# regular expression path.match(/user/);

Tags: javascript, regex

```
   var path = '/user/tobi'

   path.match(/user/);
      //result: ["user"]
   path.match(/(user)/);
    //result: ["user", "user”]
```

Why adding a '()', will result a two user result?

Comment: http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm use this free tool to understand regular expression of any complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [regexps documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns array consisting of a matching string and all [submatches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parenthesized_Substring_Matches), declared by regexps in parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Because capturing their contents is what parentheses do in a regular expression. The zero-th element is the whole match, each subsequent one corresponds to a "capture group" (i.e. parenthesis pair), in the order of their introduction.

Demo:

```
path.match(/(u)s((e)(r))/)
    //result: ["user", "u", "er", "e", "r"]
```

Comment: so "u", "er", "e", "r" are all sub-match for "user". Is this correct? There is no sub sub match, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not specified g in your regular expression therefore match function behaves as 
regexp.exec(string). and as per its documentation the result of exec method contains matched sub strings and capturing parenthesis.

please check following URLs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Fexec